# Errors when updated babel and webpack version in react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a [project](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars) who was using babel version 5, webpack version 1, and ava version 0.14.0.

After I did some updates when i run `npm run build-example` i get:

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
> Error: Multiple configuration files found. Please remove one:
>
> - package.json
> - pathto\react-stars.babelrc

[Here's my old package.json](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars/blob/master/package.json)

After updates, now I'm using babel version 7.10, webpack version 4.43, and ava version 3.10.1. Here's the updated `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react-rating-stars-component",
  "version": "2.2.0",
  "description": "Simple star rating component for your React projects.",
  "main": "dist/react-stars.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "ava": {
    "babel": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
      ]
    },
    "require": [
      "babel-register"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "dev": "babel src --out-dir dist --watch",
    "build-example": "webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "dev-example": "webpack-dev-server . --hot --inline"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "star",
    "rating",
    "react",
    "stars",
    "rating",
    "component",
    "raty",
    "rate",
    "reactjs",
    "ratings"
  ],
  "author": "Ertan Hasani",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^3.10.1",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

[Here's my old webpack.production.config.js](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars/blob/master/webpack.production.config.js)

Here's the updated `webpack.production.config.js`:

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {

  entry: ['./example/index.js'],

  output: {
    filename: './example/bundle.js',
    pathinfo: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env']
      }
    }]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ],

  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};
```

[Here's my old `webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

my updated `webpack.config.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

  entry: ['./example/index.js'],

  debug: true,

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  output: {
    filename: './example/bundle.js',
    pathinfo: true
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env']
      }
    }]
  }

};
```

I also updated `.babelrc. file:

[Here's my old `.babelrc` file!](https://github.com/ertanhasani/react-stars/blob/master/.babelrc)

my updated `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have multiple configurations as mentioned in the error message, I'd suggest removing the following configuration lines from your `package.json` file and operate your babel configurations exclusively from the `.babelrc` file in your project root

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
```